# Can't align horizontal scrollbar properly

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Python beginner here. Horizontal scrollbar not working properly: it won't stretch out the whole window width. However vertical scrollbar and everything else works perfectly fine. What could be the problem?

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def listwindow():
    list_window = Toplevel()

    list_window.geometry("1000x300")
    list_window.title("List Presentation")
    list_window.config(background="#232323")

    main_frame = Frame(list_window)
    main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    mcanvas = Canvas(main_frame)
    mcanvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    mscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=mcanvas.xview)
    mscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    mscrollbar2 = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=mcanvas.yview)
    mscrollbar2.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    mcanvas.configure(xscrollcommand=mscrollbar.set)
    mcanvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: mcanvas.configure(scrollregion=mcanvas.bbox("all")))

    mcanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=mscrollbar2.set)
    mcanvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: mcanvas.configure(scrollregion=mcanvas.bbox("all")))

    second_frame = Frame(mcanvas)

    mcanvas.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")

    for i in range(len(googleimg.searchlist)):
        globals()["itemImage"+str(i + 1)] = PhotoImage(file="D:\\Photos\\listcreator\\" + str(googleimg.targetpath) + "\\resized\\"+str(i+1)+".png")
        globals()["labelImage" + str(i + 1)] = Label(second_frame,image=globals()["itemImage"+str(i+1)]).grid(row=0,column=i)

    list_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WEY9lXH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of calling `.pack()` matters:

```py
mscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
mscrollbar2.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
mcanvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```